# jackrabbit accessmanager: How to create ACL with restriction rep:glob="/foo"

Tags: sling, crx, jackrabbit-oak

We installed the Accessmanager Bundle and now we are creating our ACL inside the JCR using curl commands.

For example:

```
curl -u admin:XXX -FprincipalId=testgroup -Fprivilege@jcr:read=denied http://myhost:4502/content.modifyAce.html`
```

But I have no idea how to create an `ACL` with a restriction like `rep:glob="/foo"`?

Is this even possible?

I know this is working when I use the `CrxDe` `UI`.
But we need to do this from commandline.

Thank you!